How can the computable numbers be countable?
So Turing proved that computable numbers are countably infinite. I think his reasoning is essentially because you can make a list of Turing machines where each machine appears only once and each machine calculates a computable number to arbitrary precision. But building this list seems to pose some challenges.
For starters, some numbers on the list will be extremely hard to calculate. Take for example a machine that takes exponentially longer to calculate each successive digit. But this isn't a problem so long as we have infinite time to wait, or an impossibly fast computer.
The real issue I have is halting. Say that if a machine halts, we write the remaining digits as 0s. Also, say that if a machine gets stuck in an infinite loop, it will produce no further digits, so we can again write the rest of the digits as 0. A problem arises because some machines will get stuck, and there will be no way to know if it will produce a digit in 10 minutes, 10 trillion years, or if it is stuck forever. Thus, for some numbers on the list we will have the first few digits but will not know whether or not there are any more. Hence, the list includes numbers that we cannot know what they are to arbitrary precision. Is it fair to include them in the list of computable numbers? We cannot remove these machines because, if we do, some of them could be computable numbers that don't appear elsewhere, we have no way of knowing.

The Turing machines that don't get stuck will even be less, still countable.

What's your question?  If you fix a universal Turing machine, there are only countably many programs which can be run.  Sure, some of these won't halt and sure, we don't know which ones those are.  So, the ones which do in fact halt are just a subset.  And a subset of a countable set is countable.

My understanding is that if the machine doesn't halt, then the number isn't a computable number.  However, if the machine just takes a long time, then it is a computable number.  The issue with the halting problem is that we can't actually know if it is a computable number.
However, since the number of machines which produce computable numbers are countable (it is less than or equal to the total number of machines) then we know that the comptuable numbers are countable infinity.

A turing machine that calculates 3.14159 and then halts hasn't really calculated pi. It has to run forever, and even though we don't wait for it to finish, we know that machine represents pi because we know how the program works.

@johnnyb: "...then the number isn't a computable number." I have to ask : which number isn't a computable number?

The preliminary question must be: is the set of computable functions countable, or not? (And note it's not the same question as asking whether there are countably many programs, that's obvious.)

The BBP algorithm for $\pi$ is a spigot algorithm, so $\pi$ is very efficiently computable.  But even if it weren't, this would not change that the set of (finite) Turing machine specifications is countably infinite.  I.e., we don't have to know which computable number any TM on the list computes.  If it computes a number, it's a computable one.

@TonyK - more precisely I should have said that if the machine doesn't halt, it doesn't generate a computable number, and there is no associated computable number with that machine.

To be clear, the computable numbers are real numbers which can be calculated to arbitrary precision by a finite, terminating algorithm - or in other words, by a halting Turing machine. However, to use the more formal definition:

A real number $a$ is computable if it can be approximated by some computable function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ in the following manner: given any positive integer $n$, the function produces an integer $f(n)$ such that:


$${f(n)-1\over n} \leq a \leq {f(n)+1\over n}$$

By the Church-Turing thesis, there is an exact correspondence between the computable functions and Turing machines, so this is saying that there is a TM that takes input $n$ and outputs a value within $an \pm 1$. For example, if we can make a TM that has outputs that include $f(1) = 3$, $f(10) = 31$, $f(100) = 314$, and so on with appropriate interpolations for other inputs, then we can claim $\pi$ is computable.
It is tricky, though, since the set of computable numbers (or at least the set of Godel numbers that map to TMs that define the computable numbers) is not computably enumerable, meaning that you can't generate a list of the relevant TMs and hence list out all the computable numbers. On the other hand, given a computable number in some form it should be theoretically possible to prove its computability, presumably also leading to the TM that generates it.
Or to put it another way, infinity is weird.

Countability is a set-theoretic notion and only cares about the existence of an injective function into the natural numbers.
Hence, let $B$ be countable via the injective function $f:B\to\mathbb{N}$. Then
any subset $A\subseteq B$ is countable itself, via the restriction $f\mid_A$ of $f$.
Assuming the Church-Turing thesis, Computability is the same as Turing-computability. Since there are only countably many Turing machines and for each only countable many inputs (the alphabet is finite), they can only compute countably many distinct objects ($\mid \aleph_0\times\aleph_0\mid = \aleph_0$). Hence, everything computable by Turing machines is countable.
